load_ledger_cli_owners not working in safe-cli
When a replayed account is loaded in Safe-CLI it shows:
Ledger=Disabled  Optional ledger library is not installed, run pip install safe-cli[ledger] 
Trezor=Disabled  Optional trezor library is not installed, run pip install safe-cli[trezor] 

So when I run load_ledger_cli_owners there's no response.
I've also tried
load_ledger_cli_owners --derivation-path m/44'/60'/0'/0/0

But '/60' becomes red.
How do I "run pip install safe-cli[ledger]"?
Many thanks in advance.

You simply need to type pip install "safe-cli[ledger]" in your command invite (the same place where you typed load_ledger_cli_owners ...) and press enter ↵ to execute the command.
If the installation is successful you should then be able to retry load_ledger_cli_owners.
Can please you confirm it worked?
Thanks in advance 
Best, Louis

Resolved! And finally able to use Safe CLI + Ledger to recover fund in a replayed Base account. Much thanks, Louis. 1 caveat/update I'd add here to improve your remedy: For Base, instead of Infura whose Base endpoint is still in beta (meaning "base-mainnet.infura.io/v3/" won't work), point folks to other services: https://docs.base.org/docs/tools/node-providers/
Best

Cool, very happy it worked!  Thanks for the heads-up, I'll pass it on to the team and we'll probably patch it as Base is used by a lot of Safe users. Thank you for that
